# split a list a sentence by point with python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list of sentence :

```
['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you. By the way']
```

I need to split each sentence into list when I found "."  .

For example, in the example above, the expected result is :

```
['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you'. 'By the way']
```

I try with this code in python :

```
def split_pint(result):
    for i in result:
        i = re.split(r". ", i)
    return result
```

But the sentence wasn't split.

Any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a simple iteration and `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
data = ['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you. By the way']

def split_pint(data):
    result = []
    for elem in data:
        result.extend(elem.split(". "))        
    return result

print(split_pint(data))
```

**Output:**

```
['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you', 'By the way']
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not the way to modify a list, as you can see:

```
l = [0, 0]
for x in l:
    x = 1
print(l)
# [0, 0]
```

Anyway, if you want to use `re.split` you'll need to escape `.` character:

```
import re

l = ['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you. By the way']
def split_pint(result):
    res = []
    for i in result:
        res += re.split("\. ", i)
    return res


print(split_pint(l))
['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you', 'By the way']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, but one-liner and in a functional programming way:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = ['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you. By the way']
>>> reduce(lambda i, j: i + j, map(lambda s: s.split('. '), a))
['hello', 'I would like to thank you', 'I would like to thank you', 'By the way']
```

First, `map` makes a list from each string, and second, `reduce` just concatenates all lists.